# Bridge is nil when calling methods on React Native bridge, use a singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am working through creating my own custom component, to interact with a Bluetooth device.  [I tried this in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975158/proper-process-for-sending-swift-events-to-javascript-in-react-native), but didn't get anywhere due to problems with accessing the bridge.

I reimplemented it in Objective-C and experienced the same problem (`bridge = nil`).  To fix it, I used:

**BTAdapter.h**

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface BTAdapter : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>
- (void)sendEvent:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

**BTAdapter.m**

```
#import "BTAdapter.h"

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@implementation BTAdapter

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *) zone
{
    static BTAdapter *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}


- (void)sendEvent:(NSString *)name
{
    NSLog(@"Received generic event in the bridge");
    if (self.bridge == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Bridge is nil"); // This happens normally
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Bridge is NOT nil"); // This happens with a singleton
    }
    [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:name body:@"Event from the bridge"];
}
```

Add to my `Bridging-Header.h`:

```
#import "BTAdapter.h"
```

And I'm calling it in Swift like:

```
let adapter: BTAdapter = BTAdapter()
adapter.sendEvent("TestEvent")
```

Is this a bad thing to do?  I followed a pretty outdated React Native GitHub issue on a similar topic, but there wasn't a whole lot of certainty surrounding this solution. [This seems to suggest it's not a good idea at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879266/cant-send-an-event-from-main-thread-method-with-ios-and-react-native)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem until I removed my own initializer code. If you need configuration, I recommend you use `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` to call in and prepare your module.

Comment: Thanks for this, you're absolutely right. Manually instantiating my bridge module was the reason the bridge was always nil.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. How do I access my module (from Obj-C) without instantiating it, i.e. is there a hook or something to the module when it is instantiated by the system?
Kind of stuck in this and your question looked the most like my situation.

Comment: @stephanmantel AFAIK there's not...you can create your own config method using `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD`. As usual, mind the information in the guides about not making thread assumptions, etc